# How to use jQuery to check if element breaks to the next line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I have a setup that displays two elements side-by-side, specifically an image and a Facebook like box.

The image has `float:left` and the Facebook like box div/span has `float:right` - the HTML code looks something like so:

```
<div class="header"><img class="logo" src="logo.jpg"><span class="fb-like-box"><iframe></iframe></span></div>
```

In certain situations when the browser width shrinks to a certain point, the FB like box will break (or move) to the next line. I have used CSS @media queries to deal with this.

**Unfortunately**, certain mobile browsers do not 'break' or move the FB like box to the next line at the same CSS points. For example it renders fine on a 320px width iPhone and a 360px width Note 2. However, on say the Samsung stock browser with a phone width of 380px, the Facebook like box is displayed on the next line and actually the box itself is rendered horribly.

How do I use jQuery to detect if a floating element is displayed on (or breaks to) the next line and execute a CSS modification?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess if element breaks into new line..Height of the parent should be getting reflected...can't you deal with that ?

Comment: Good point unfortunately the height of the parent fluctuates quite a lot as the browser width changes. If there isn't a better answer maybe I'll have to go with this.

Comment: Possibly compare the position().top values of each element; if the FB likebox is N pixels difference (where N is a value large enough to denote a line break; more than a few pixels), then it's probably a line break. https://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing `position().top` of both elements on resize or load could trigger a function containing a CSS modification.

If the absolute value of the difference between position().top of the left and right elements is greater than a certain amount, and both elements are set to align to the top of their parent element, then it would theoretically mean it's probably a line break.

See jsfiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/aprtLumf/2/

jQuery position() documentation: https://api.jquery.com/position/